# iOS view constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, constraints, xib

I have a problem with view constraints I created in portrait mode. I'm not sure if it's a right approach but I needed a fullscreen UIImageView so I created it in portrait mode, and then added constraints spacing to top, right, bottom, left equal 0.

When run my app in portrait mode it works ok - the view has dimensions 768,1024 and then when I rotate to landscape mode it has dimensions 1024,768.

The problem is when I run this app while in landscape mode - it has dimensions 768,1024 instead of 1024,768. It comes back to normal when I rotate my device...

It looks like constraints are taken into account only after the device is rotated..?

Comment: an unfortunate reality .. try programmatically setting the frame of `ImageView` to bounds of `self.view` in `willAnimateRotationToInteraceOrientation:duration:` method.

Comment: but this method is called only during rotation... my problem is before rotation when I run my app in landscape mode. I guess I have to hardcode size of my view in viewdidload method, but I was looking for some better way to do this.

Comment: in viewWillAppear, call this method manually until you find a better solution. ;)